# How to fix untermined string JavaScript error when I load resources?

Tags: javascript, debugging, scripting, resources

I'm getting untermined string literal errors when I load resources like:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And while debugging console actually says this error is on those lines where I put these scripts.

Comment: I'm not seeing any untermited string literal... but I do see jquery loaded multiple times... what is wrong :) Do you have exactly that? Console may be pointing to incorrect line.

Comment: Do you mean "unterminated"?

Comment: yes sorry, unterminated